# Loop and groupby for column values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
STOP_SEQ    STOP_ID Bearing
6   82207   S
6   82207   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
3   23770   N
3   23770   N
3   23770   N
3   23770   N
6   82207   S
6   82207   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
7   82216   S
6   82207   S
6   82207   S
6   82207   S
6   82207   S
6   82207   S
6   82207   S
6   82207   S
21  23600   W
25  82165   N
28  82185   N
31  82197   N
31  82197   N
31  82197   N
31  82197   N
31  82197   N
31  82197   N
31  82197   N
31  82197   N
32  82198   W
32  82198   W
32  82198   W
32  82198   W
32  82198   W
32  82198   W
32  82198   W
```

I wrote the following code for split these data based on column value into different sheets:

```
import pandas as pd
from pd import ExcelWriter
df = pd.read_excel (stations)
l = df.groupby("STOP_ID")
enter code here
```

How could I insert each group into a different excel sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the groupby (keys and values):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
for name, sub_df in df.groupby("STOP_ID")):
    sub_df.to_excel(writer, str(name))
writer.save()
```

Comment: what if i want to split them to different excel files?

Comment: You can do `to_excel(name + ".xlsx")` instead of using the writer.

Comment: thank you andy but i did it using (strname)+" .xlsx')